# Find internal and external IP and port, NAT, ISP

Tags: ip, nat

How do I get the internal IP address and port of the local machine in a cross-platform way? Not internal within the LAN, but the ISP, so that other users of the ISP can connect? Is connecting to a VPS with a public IP enough to get the external IP and port outside the ISP? How to get the ISP subnet mask to know when another internal IP is within the NAT?

edit: Probably don't need this. NAT punch through is enough. Am I right that router's don't have the same traversal rules as ISP's?

Answer (score 1):

A NAT's public IP address is its external IP address. I don't understand what you mean by internal IP address. By internal address usually is meant a device's local address.

All the users of an ISP is in local LAN if the ISP has only one NAT under which all the private IP address is assigned. Some ISPs has nested NATs. In that case users under different NATs are in different network.

You can get your NAT's external IP:Port by sending a stun request to a stun server. From the server's reply you can get your NAT's external/public IP:Port. If the users of an ISP are not in local LAN but under different NATs then using their external IP:port they can communicate.